Numpy and Other Python Packages Acting Up
I recently upgraded from a 2015 MacBook Pro to a 2023 MacBook Pro, and my old MacBook was running on the X86_64 arcitecture, whereas my new one uses arm64 architecture. I uninstalled python for X86_64 and reinstalled every terminal plugin that I had installed (quite some work). Everyting appears to work, except packages that rely on numpy. Numpy itself works fine:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)
>>> print(array)
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]

But when I try to run a package (such as pyinstaller, eg pyinstaller --onefile <my-program.py>), I get an error saying that it needs X86_64 arcitecture, when it has arm64:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_console_script_run())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 231, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 215, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 70, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1227, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1167, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/Users/Micah/Documents/Tech/Coding/Programs/Python/SYSOS/sysos.spec", line 19, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
          ^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(
               ^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 254, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 314, in assemble
    src_name = process_collected_binary(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/utils.py", line 309, in process_collected_binary
    osxutils.binary_to_target_arch(cached_name, target_arch, display_name=src_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyinstaller/6.10.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 351, in binary_to_target_arch
    raise IncompatibleBinaryArchError(
PyInstaller.utils.osx.IncompatibleBinaryArchError: /Users/Micah/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/_core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-darwin.so is incompatible with target arch x86_64 (has arch: arm64)!

I have already tried reinstalling python for arm64, this fixed some issues, but not this one. I cleaned my system of conflicting python versions. which python3 reports that I am using the correct version of python. I have also run arch -arm64 pip3 install numpy, which does nothing to fix the issue.

Just a guess: Could there be a .spec file which specifies the wrong target architecture? See https://pyinstaller.org/en/v6.10.0/spec-files.html#using-spec-files

My spec file doesn't appear to have anything in it that would refer to X86-64.

By default, uninstalling Python does not remove all pip packages.
You should try removing all your packages, and reinstalling pyinstaller with your new ARM64 python:
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
pip install pyinstaller


Whenever I run pip3 uninstall pyinstaller, it says something about externally managed environment.
